# The camera view of UIImagePickerController has a big gap above it for iPhone 12 Pro, no other phones have this gap

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I am using the camera of UIImagePickerController. Here is some simplified code to present it

```
let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imagePickerController.sourceType = .camera
        imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = false
        imagePickerController.cameraCaptureMode = .photo
        
//        if traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == .compact  || traitCollection.verticalSizeClass == .compact {
//            let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
//            let previewRatio: CGFloat = 4 / 3
//            let previewHeight = screenSize.width * previewRatio
//            let offset = (screenSize.height - previewHeight) / 2
//            imagePickerController.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: offset)
//        }
        
        showImagePickerController()
    }
    
    private func showImagePickerController() {
        addChild(imagePickerController)
        view.addSubview(imagePickerController.view)
        imagePickerController.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
```

On every device up until now the camera preview view would show up at the top as expected:
[image]

But on iPhone 12 Pro it has a big gap at the top:
[image]

If I uncomment out the lines in the code the image is centered on all iPhones except the iPhone 12 Pro now. For that device it is centered plus original top gap, so lower than center.

Is this a bug on Apple's side?